# Spring Quartz Scheduler - Run job after the other has completed

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have two jobs configured as cronTriggerBeans. They are added to a quartz SchedulerFactoryBean. They run at different times but modify same set of data in a database. Problem occurs on particular occasions when the job running time is the same. In this scenario, I want job2 to wait for job2 to be completed. I realize there is a way to implement this scenario if it's the case every single time. But in my case, one job runs every 1 hour and the other every 24 hours. So when the 24 hours job run, I want to have the hourly job to be finished. How can I achieve it.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="hourlyJob"/>
                <ref bean="twentyFourHourlyJob"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="hourlyJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
       // bean configurations

<bean id="twentyFourHourlyJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        // bean configurations
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Job Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) to configure flow and for example run the second job after finishing the other method or run it directly from the body from the first job.

Look here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#external-flows

Comment: running the second job from the body of first job is not an option as the second job will not run every time the first job run.